# Why does the following script throw database still in use when selecting the master database first?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Why does the following SQL query throw an error when I've first selected the master database before dropping the database in question?

Please see error and code below:

> Msg 3702, Level 16, State 4, Line 5
> Cannot drop database "XyzCompany" because it is currently in use.
>
> Msg 1801, Level 16, State 3, Line 7
> Database 'XyzCompany' already exists. Choose a different database name.

Code:

```
USE master;
GO

DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS XyzCompany;

CREATE DATABASE XyzCompany;
GO

USE XyzCompany;
GO
```

Comment: There might be other connections against your database which keeps it from being dropped. Check: `select distinct request_session_id from sys.dm_tran_locks where resource_database_id = db_id('YourDB')`

Comment: When running `SELECT DISTINCT REQUEST_SESSION_ID FROM sys.dm_tran_locks WHERE RESOURCE_DATABASE_ID = db_id('XyzCompany')` it does return a REQUEST_SESSION_ID of 53, so my question is how do I totally disconnect from the database if the query you mentioned above returns a value?

Comment: you can do: `KILL 53;` note that it might be a good idea to check who this session is. You can check: `select * from sys.dm_exec_sessions where session_id = 53` so you don't kill someone who needs to be connected

Comment: It does thanks, I just thought it would be as easy as it is in MySQL, but I guess Microsoft has it's reasons for doing it their way :-)!

Comment: Try putting  `GO` after the `DROP DATABASE ...` line.  I don't think that Atomic syntax was supported in 2008.